# Compute matrix in R

Tags: r

Body mass index (BMI) is a biometric measure of the relationship between height and weight of an individual. The BMI data were compiled in the following vector:

`imc <- c (18, 19, 24, 25, 30, 35, 30, 20, 18, 15)`

The criterion of experts to classify the groups is the following:

> low (<18.55);  Normal (18.55-25) and  overweight (> 30)

With this information create a vector of factors called `imcRangos` from `imc` that shows the values `low`, `normal` and `overweight`.

I need some help with it.

Comment: Can you provide an example for the desired output please?

Comment: well, I´d desire obtain a table with the values for: low, normal and overweight

Answer (score 1):

Even though you don't provide an appropriate example for your desired output, I try to answer your question based on how I understand your posting.

If you want a simple assignment of the values `low`, `normal` and `overweight` to the BMI values, you can use `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

imc <- c(18, 19, 24, 25, 30, 35, 30, 20, 18, 15)

table <- data.frame(imc) %>%
  mutate(imcRangos = ifelse(imc < 18.55, "low", ifelse(imc > 30, "overweight", "normal")))
```

The result looks like this:

```
   imc  imcRangos
1   18        low
2   19     normal
3   24     normal
4   25     normal
5   30     normal
6   35 overweight
7   30     normal
8   20     normal
9   18        low
10  15        low
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this easily with `cut` or `foverlaps`

```
cut(imc, breaks = c(-Inf, 18.55, 30, Inf), labels = c("low", "normal", "overweight"))
#[1] low        normal     normal     normal     normal     overweight normal     normal    
#[9] low        low       
#Levels: low normal overweight
```